# fetching record from more than 2 tables using join

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables A and B  having different field , and one common field:[image]

I am using join query and getting result as snapshot in image 3. Using below query

```
SELECT c.* , p.* 
FROM T1 c right join T2 p ON c.id=p.stu_id 
WHERE c.id=8
```

actually I don't want the repeated result from T1 , as getting

Comment: as showing in image i dont want the repeated record id , enroll,form_no,stu_name,fname,course,ad_date, these record should be appears only once ,

Comment: From a database SQL perspective, the result set you see is what is expected. Removing the repeating elements for display purposes is best done outside the database i.e. in PHP when looping thru the records. You can check to see if the current id, name, etc. are same as previous and then decide whether to display or hide this information.

Answer (score 1):

=>Try this query.

```
$select = "SELECT C.id  as fildname 
           FROM table_name as T 
           JOIN table_name as C  
           ON  T.id = C.fildname 
           WHERE  B.id=".$Tid;
$result = mysql_query($select) or die (mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

OR

```
//get one to many fild ...

$sql = "SELECT B.firstname as user_name,
               B.lastname as Lastname,
               B.email as Email,
               B.phone as Phone, 
               B.address as Address, B.city as City,
               B.state as State,     
               B.pincode as Pincode ,V.firstname as 
               vehicle_name,V.lastname as Vlastname,
               V.email as Vemail,V.phone as Vphone,
               V.address as Vaddress, 
               V.city as Vcity, V.state as Vstate,
               V.pincode as Vpincode 
               FROM broker_table as B , vehicle_table as V 
               where B.id='".$row['c_id']."'";
```

Comment: its only retuning a single field that is id , as u r seeing in image record like name , fname which are repeating again and again only that i dont want , but i want all values of tot_fee, Fee_rec,rcno,fee_date.